# Finding the integral of an inverse cosine function?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I've just been having trouble with this question:

"Differentiate $xcos^{-1}x$ and hence find the integral of $cos^{-1}x$. 
Hint: Try using the substitution $u=1-x^2$."

Finding the derivative wasn't difficult, but I don't understand how this may correlate with the integral question.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Integration by parts!

Comment: I haven't learnt that, just plain substitution with one variable: $u$. Is there any other way of approaching this question or is this not achievable with my current knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x \cos^{-1}x\right) = \cos^{-1}x - \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
Let us now integrate both members and we get:
$$
x\cos^{-1}x = \int \cos^{-1}x\ \mathrm{d}x - \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm{d}x
$$

$$
\int \cos^{-1}x\ \mathrm{d}x = x\cos^{-1}x + \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm{d}x.
$$
The last integral can now be solved with the substitution in the hint you mentioned!

Comment: This is perfect, thanks :D